# How to send dynamic(personalization ) content in push notification through api

Tags: api, push, cloud, marketing-cloud

The below link talks about Push send api  ,
But limited to how we can send personalization string  .

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postMessageContactSendPush.htm

How can we make use of the api to send personalization message for each user .

Comment: Can you please tell more about what you tried so far?

Comment: Use ampscript in push template to retrieve subscriber id which we are passing from api call and use look up to search required fields corresponding to that subscriber id to be displayed as persionalization string in the message

Comment: and by passing you mean that you insert data into a DE and from there you retrieve the information? Is that possible? Or are you doing 2 calls. One for the data and one for the actual message?